# Removing \ from php/mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have an insert statement using php/mysql in a WordPress environment and when someone creates a new entry that has an apostrophe in the title (like Mike's Post) the database adds an \ into the name. So it looks like Mike\'s Post in mysql. How can I remove this when the sql insert is performed so it inserts as Mike's Post. I'm not sure if Wordpress gets in the way and complicate things not.

NOTE: stripslashes has done nothing so far and I am on shared hosting so I cannot access php.ini, but I assume magic quotes are on.

```
echo "<td><a href=\"http://example.com?writing=$all[SID]\">$all2[name]</a></td>";
```

Comment: That sounds like your input is being escaped _twice_. Find the offending code and fix it.

Comment: can you post your code here.

Comment: @Halcyon I'm not doing any escaping. Simple sql select and the output line shown in post above. I imagine php.ini has magic quotes on but I can't check with shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

Don’t care the char. just for safe with mysql_* function.

Please check `magic_quotes_gpc` option in php.ini.

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){ //enabled
  //Auto stripped without the slashes when you select the row .

} else {  //disabld
  //Please use stripslashes to stripped slashes.
  $col = stripslashes($row['col']);
}
```

> stripslashes()
>
> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be
>   escaped. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("),
>   backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Hmm. So if try stripping out the \ on the output as you suggest, how might I work your code into my current output line that looks like this:      echo "<a href=\"http://example.com?writing=$all[SID]\">$all2[story_name]</a>";

Comment: I can't access php.ini because my site is on shared WordPress hosting. I did try your code above it did not do anything and I still have the \ before any apostrophes

Answer (score 0):

Someone proposed an answer that was close. However, the issue was that magic quotes was enabled most likely even though it was still adding the \ . Therefore, the else statement where the real solution lies was not getting executed. The solution, at least in Wordpress, is to simply add this into to your loop, but NOT as an if...else.

```
foreach ($row1 as $row2) {
$strip = stripslashes($row2['col']);
echo "<td><a href=\"http://example.com\">$strip</a></td>";
```